# SQL query to show AWS RDS Oracle instance information

Tags: oracle, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I am using Oracle Database in AWS RDS (r19). I am trying to extract some information about the instance using SQL statements only. I can reliably query the vCPU counts and also get relevant SGA details.

How can I determine the RDS instance information, like RDS type (for example "db.m5.xlarge") and perhaps region details, and standby info (if any) with SQL queries only? I want to see if this can be done exclusively using SQL from within the database. The information needed is the instance type.

Let me know if I can provide any additional details or clarifications.

Thanks.

Comment: Your question may in fact be an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/) - why do you want to do this? It would be better if you tell us the overall problem that you're trying to solve rather than how you're currently trying to solve it.

Comment: Thanks for the note. I am acutely aware of the XY problem. In my situation, I am an auditor collecting forensic information with restrictions on what I can do. I am not implementing anything and cannot recommend any changes or modifications to the auditee's environment. I hope this helps.

Comment: Instance type and any other hardware or OS-level details would have to be determined from the AWS console or APIs. Oracle database wouldn't know anything about that internally.